# Twin Primes, Ciphers, Sum of Two Cubes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I'm studying for my Number Theory final and I have a few review questions that are stumping me...

1. Find the twin primes which satisfy $\varphi(pq)=1680$. Explain your reasoning.
2. The ciphertext below was encrypted using the Hill cipher:
   $$C_1\equiv4P_1+1P_2\bmod26$$
   $$C_2\equiv3P_1+2P_2\bmod26$$
   Using the Hill cipher decipher the famous quote
   `ZKKLKHFTHUVWVYYCMY`
3. Show that if $n\equiv3,4,5,6\bmod9$ then $n$ is not the sum of two cubes.

Comment: But what's a Hill cipher?

Comment: What are your thoughts on these problems? What have you tried yourself before posting this question?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel a simple google search would've been enough to answer that question: see [Hill cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher)

Answer (score 2):

1. $\phi(pq)=(p-1)(q-1)$ but $q=p+2$ and so it's easy to solve $\phi(pq)=1680$ for $p$.
2. Is the cypher encoding pairs of letters? If so,
   $$
   \pmatrix{ P_1 \\ P_2 } \equiv -5 \pmatrix{ \hphantom{-}2 & -1 \\ -3 & \hphantom{-}4 } \pmatrix{ C_1 \\ C_2 } \bmod 26
   $$
3. Just compute the cubes of $0, 1, \dots 8 \bmod 9$ and see what sums you get.